# Why does a thermal memory need a thermal bath?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, phonons, computer

In the article "Thermal Memory: A Storage of Phononic Information
Phys. Rev. Lett. 101, 267203 – Published 29 December 2008" it's said that a thermal memory need a thermal bath, similar to a power supply in electronic memory, to avoid that thermal fluctuations destroy the memory.

How does a thermal bath prevent that thermal fluctuations destroy the thermal memory?

**Addition**.  The paragraph of the mentioned article is:

> Like an electronic memory that records data by maintaining voltage in a capacitance, a thermal memory stores
>   data by keeping temperature somewhere. Therefore, any
>   thermally insulated system might be a candidate for thermal memory since it keeps its temperature (thus data) for a
>   very long time. However, perturbation is unavoidable in
>   such a thermal system, especially when the data are read
>   out, namely, the local temperature is measured. Generally,
>   without external energy source or sink, any thermally
>   insulated system will not be able to recover its original
>   state after the data reading (temperature measuring) process, because there exists energy exchange between the
>   system and the reader (thermometer) during this process.
>   We thus have to turn to a thermal-circuit with power
>   supply, i.e., driven by external heat bath.

Comment: May I copy the paragraph that explain this point to clarify my question?

Comment: Yes I think that would be OK - if (as you did) you quote the source.

Comment: Yes, you not only _can_, but _should_ copy the relevant part of the article (given that it is short). The question should make sense even to readers who are unable to access the original source. (Of course it's necessary to attribute the source of any quote, and properly identify it as a quote.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation (based on reading the paragraph - no deep background in the physics of these devices so keep that in mind as you take this in):

What this is saying is that if you store information as "heat", then the process of measuring the temperature of a "bit" requires some heat to flow - and this will in turn lower the temperature of the element you are measuring. In order to prevent the process of repeated measurement from zeroing out the heat differences, you need to pump back the heat you lost by measurement. Hence the need for a heat source.

Comment: I was thinking something about that but I was not sure, because we can imagine no intrusive measurement technique (like detecting the IR radiation or measuring the scattering of a light probe).  Thank you, Floris.